# How to get rid of this fatal error while logging in Wordpress on localhost?

Tags: wordpress

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/custom-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme\functions.php on line 496

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/custom-header.php' (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\mytheme\functions.php on line 496

Comment: Try to describe what you did, what is working and what is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you either have a require/require_once or get get_template_part function that's looking for your custom-header.php file on line 496 in your functions.php file to fix this either create a custom header.php file under the location C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/custom-header.php

or delete line 496 that's referencing the file that doesn't exist on your functions.php